# Javascript page freezes

Tags: javascript

I am having a problem with a javascript code, it is a code the runs when I click a button. 
**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
                var key = '';
                var c = 22;
                var size = data[7].length;
                for(var t = 22; t < size; ++t){
                    while(!(data[7][c] === "<")){
                        key += data[7][c];
                        ++c;
                    }
                }
```

This code works perfectly, although when I add the following line and I click the button, the page freezes like an infinite loop.

**Data Content**

```
<span class="keyword">casa</span>
```

**NEW LINE**

```
                var key = '';
                var c = 22;
                var size = data[7].length;
                for(var t = 22; t < size; ++t){
                    while(!(data[7][c] === "<")){
                        key += data[7][c];
                        ++c;
                    }
                t = c; //NEW LINE
                }
```

Both c and t have the same typeof == number
If you are wondering why I use two variables, it is because I have trying to solve this problem in many ways

Thanks!

Comment: You should provide more details as what is the value of `data` array. You can also try to debug the problem by doing `console.log` and printing the value of t & c in each loop.

Comment: You could try using the debug tools in the browser to set a breakpoint on `t = c` and see what value `t` is set to. My guess is that `c` is always less than `size`, so your `for` loop never exits

Comment: If the code worked perfectly, why are you adding that line?

Comment: In fact the inside while loop only executes once

Comment: Because I works,  but it doesn't do what I need it to do

Comment: If it doesn't do what you need it to do, then *it doesn't work*.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to add text like "SOLVED" to the title. Accept an answer if it helped you fix the issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: that's because the loop becomes infinite eventually. To be precise, at the point, when `while` condition is no longer true and both `t` and `c` are still less than `size`.

Comment: Found the mistake, at the end of the loop t value resets

Comment: @pol exactly, and how one would expect it *not* to reset after adding that line? :)

Comment: Yes, it was a dumb mistake